# How to specify RPATH in a makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, ld, rpath, ldflags

I'm trying to specify rpath in my binary. 
My makefile looks like this-

```
CC=gcc 
CFLAGS=-Wall
LDFLAGS= -rpath='../libs/'
main: main.c  
    gcc -o main main.c

clean:
    rm -f main main.o
```

But when I query rpath using command `readelf -a ./main | grep rpath` I get nothing 
I've tried specifying rpath as `LDFLAGS= "-rpath=../libs/"` but even that doesn't seem to work.

Can someone please post an example on how should I specify rpath in a makefile?

GCC and ld versions are-

```
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.21.0.20110327
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you set the variables, you should probably use them.  It's silly not to, especially when make won't magically set those variables for you!  :)

```
main: main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o main main.c
```

---

Another problem is `LDFLAGS`, it should be

```
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,../libs/"
```

The usual *gcc* switch for passing options to linker is `-Wl,`, and it is needed because *gcc* itself may not understand the bare `-rpath` linker option. While some builds of various versions of *gcc* accept `-rpath`, I have never seen it documented in *gcc* man pages or info pages. For better portability, `-Wl,-rpath` should be preferred.

Comment: After updating makefile, I get below error- gcc: unrecognized option '-rpath=../libs/'

Comment: It's a tiny point but, in case anyone was wondering, just to add that complete paths are also valid in the rpaths like
 `LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,/mnt/us/extensions/thing/usr/lib/"`

Comment: @twobob Do you know that the value of rpath can be symlink ?

Comment: @szydan that was on a FAT drive, sadly would be detected as a cross link and nerfed I think.

I tend to use http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/1999-04n/msg01105.html these days after the fact.

Comment: How about generating the rdpath from `realpath`? That seems to be the only way I can make a dynamically linked program work from several directories (as in `bin/prog` vs. `prog` from `bin/` and libraries in a separate directory like `lib`.) That's also the way I associate resources like shaders.

Comment: Thank you! exactly what the problem was on my system!