# oracle connection in vscode in ubuntu

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio-code

Unable to load shared library 'oci' or one of its dependencies

Hello,
I am developing a program in C #, Ubuntu 16.04 and vscode that accesses an ORACLE database.
The program portion in question is as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine("*******************************************");
Console.WriteLine("*PopulaFuncionário");
OracleConnection ora = new OracleConnection(connStr);
ora.Open();
Console.WriteLine("*Conectou na versão:" + ora.ServerVersion );
Console.WriteLine("*******************************************");
```

The Open above returns the following error.

```
Unable to load shared library 'oci' or one of its dependencies.
```

I have the ORACLE Client and the OCI libraries installed on my computer but I do not know how to reference them.
Please, if anyone has a solution ... thank you.

```cs
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'oci' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liboci: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   at System.Data.OracleClient.Oci.OciCalls.OciNativeCalls.OCIEnvCreate(IntPtr& envhpp, OciEnvironmentMode mode, IntPtr ctxp, IntPtr malocfp, IntPtr ralocfp, IntPtr mfreep, Int32 xtramem_sz, IntPtr usrmempp)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.Oci.OciEnvironmentHandle..ctor(OciEnvironmentMode mode)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.Oci.OciGlue.CreateConnection(OracleConnectionInfo conInfo)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionPoolManager.CreateConnection(OracleConnectionInfo info)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionPool.GetConnection()
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.Open()
   at app1.Models.PopulaFuncionario..ctor() in /home/w0513263/Desenv/C#/app1/Models/PopulaFuncionario.cs:line 23
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCreateInstance(CreateInstanceCallSite createInstanceCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitTransient(TransientCallSite transientCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: There is nothing referencing ```oci``` in the code you shared

Comment: Sure, something is referencing oci or this problem wouldn't be happening ...

Comment: Can you Share more of the stack trace.

Comment: I edited the question and put the full stack trace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Startup program and libocci.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249626/startup-program-and-libocci-so-11-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-fil)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching, I found the solution.
Just add the packages:

- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

and everything worked perfectly ...

Answer (score 0):

Does adding OCI_LIB_DIR to the path help?
 [image]