# Linking with specified version of the GLIBC library

Tags: gcc, linker, libraries, glibc, shared

There are two versions of the GLIBC library on my system:

1. standard /usr/lib/...
2. custom $HOME/usr/lib/...

When I compile any utility from sources using commands:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/usr
make
make install
```

it is linked with custom libraries placed in $HOME/usr/lib.

Is there a way to link it with standard GLIBC placed in /usr/lib/ but configured for installation into $HOME/usr?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is for me:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/usr LDFLAGS='-Wl,-rpath,/lib:/usr/lib'
```

Thank's for this thread: [How to specify RPATH in a makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638500/how-to-specify-rpath-in-a-makefile)